# Create a new list by comparing a common property of two lists

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a `student` class as below:

```
public class Customers
    {
        public Customers(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }        
    }
```

In a real-world scenario, I need to populate a database by reading an .xlsx file. After reading, I compare the data in the .xlsx file with the data already in the database. From these comparisons, I want to add to the database only customers whose names are in customersFromFile but are not in customersFromDataBase. Below is a representation of the scenario:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Customers> customersFromFile = new List<Customers>
            {
                new Customers(0, "James"),
                new Customers(0, "Duncan"),
                new Customers(0, "Durant"),
                new Customers(0, "Ginóbili"),
                new Customers(0, "Garnet")
            };

            List<Customers> customersFromDataBase = new List<Customers>
            {
                new Customers(0, "James"),
                new Customers(0, "Duncan"),
                new Customers(0, "Durant"),
                new Customers(0, "Ginóbili"),
                new Customers(0, "Anthony")
            };
            //I Trying this.
            var newCustomers = customersFromFile.Select(x => customersFromDataBase.Where(i => i.Name != x.Name).FirstOrDefault());
            
            
            newCustomers.ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            });

        }
    }
```

What I'm trying so far leads me to the following exit:

```
ConsoleApp2.Customers
ConsoleApp2.Customers
ConsoleApp2.Customers
ConsoleApp2.Customers
ConsoleApp2.Customers
```

But my expected output this is:

```
0, "Garnet"
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach would be like this:

```
var newCustomers = customersFromFile.Where(x => !customersFromDataBase.Any(i => i.Name == x.Name));
```

This is an `O(n²)` operation, so if you have tons of items in the list you might want to consider leveraging a data structure:

```
var existingCustomerNames = new HashSet<string>(customersFromDataBase.Select(c => c.Name));
var newCustomers = customersFromFile.Where(x => !existingCustomerNames.Contains(x.Name));
```

And just be aware that your console output won't show much right now. You could change it to show individual properties (or implement `ToString()` on the Customers class):

```
foreach(var newCustomer in newCustomers)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{newCustomer.Id}, \"{newCustomer.Name}\"");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things...

You need to change your Linq query to find items where they don't exist in another list at all.

```
var newCustomers = customersFromFile.Where(x => !customersFromDataBase.Any(i => i.Name == x.Name));
```

And, if you are relying on converting the class to a `string` then you need to add an override of the `ToString()` method inside of your `Customers` class.

```
public class Customers
{
    public Customers(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}, {1}", this.Id, this.Name);
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can simply change your `Console.WriteLine` to:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", x.Id, x.Name));
```

Comment: You need to use `Where` instead of `Select`. And please explain why overriding ToString is important. (It's only for the sake of the Console logging at the end, and there are other ways to fix that problem.)

Comment: Good corrections. I turned my down-vote into an up-vote. :-)

Answer (score -1):

What your looking for is the "Intersection" of the two collections. Linq actually has a method for this already!

From [the C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect):

```cs
Product[] store1 = { new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 },
                     new Product { Name = "orange", Code = 4 } };

Product[] store2 = { new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 },
                     new Product { Name = "lemon", Code = 12 } };

// Get the products from the first array
// that have duplicates in the second array.

IEnumerable<Product> duplicates =
    store1.Intersect(store2, new ProductComparer());

foreach (var product in duplicates)
{
    Console.WriteLine(product.Name + " " + product.Code);
}

/*
    This code produces the following output:
    apple 9
*/
```

The documentation also contains the code for the custom `ProductComparer` that is used in the above code. You will want to make an `IComparer<Customers>` for your customers model.

Comment: The way I read it, they're looking for something more like `Except` than `Intersect`.